# Bad eggs, probability question

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A farmer places 200 eggs equally in 10 boxes. 10 bad eggs were mixed with the 200 eggs.

(a) What is the probability that n boxes have 0 bad eggs? ( *I know we use binomial distribution but I just don't know how to apply it here*)

(b) Calculate the number of boxes that contain 0,1,2,... bad eggs.(*here should I find to expected value?*)

Comment: Are the bad eggs part of the $200$?

Comment: Why not start with special cases? Find the probability that all the boxes have a bad egg (i.e. the case $n = 0$), then the probability that all but one box has a bad egg (the case $n = 1$), etc. etc. and look for a pattern.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Yes the bad eggs are part of the 200.

Comment: Rivers McForge beat me to it.  I would try simplifying the problem.  Suppose that you had 6 good eggs and 2 bad ones, and they were going to be placed in 4 boxes.  What is the probability that $n$ boxes had no bad eggs, for each value of $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}.$

Comment: For part a), you don't need anything from binomial distribution; it is more of a counting problem. The wording of part b is weird; the word "expected" really should be in the problem, in which case yes, you should find the expected value.

Comment: if $n=0$ all boxes have a bad egg then you would do $(1/20)*10)$ I think